# PhoneGap/Cordova and external url instead of www/index.html

Tags: ios, cordova, appstore-approval

I'm about to build and app with Cordova.js to enable file upload on the iPhone. I'd like to just use the regular responsive web site and include the cordova.js to get access to native features like the camera.

I read somewhere that Apple might reject apps that loads external urls in an app like this. Is this true and what's the real problem?

Would it be different if the app contains a local page by default and opens external content on user interaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you app can be reproduced by a web site then Apple will just reject it. You are going to add camera features so that is a good start. If you don't use some native features they will reject it out of hand.

Secondly Apple does not like apps that load code from remote locations. They want to be able to go over everything themselves and don't like the idea of things changing without them being able to verify it first. So, remote data is okay but remote code is not in their eyes.

Comment: "remote data is okay but remote code is not in their eyes"
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Html Javascript opened in remote url is remote code? Writing lots of code just for their happiness is very time consuming, and their approval takes very long as well.